# How to upload file as blob to my table | Oracle Apex |

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-20.2, oracle-apex-20.1, oracle-apex21.2

I have been trying since yesterday no where I am able to find a proper post how to upload file as blob to table.

**Below is my table :**

```
create table upload_file
(
  fileblob  blob,
  filename  varchar2(250),
  mimetype  varchar2(250),
  createDate date
);
```

I have created a page name as `Testing` and Added below items

```
P1_CHOOSE_FILE  [ file browse ]
P1_MIMETYPE     [ Hidden ]
FILE_NAME       [ Hidden ]
CREATED         [ Hidden ]
```

On `P1_CHOOSE_FILE` , I set a property called : `Blob column specified in Item source attribute`
and value required as `ON`

Then created one Button with Dynamic action

Now my biggest challenge is How to insert my choose file to my `upload_file` table using `PL/SQL` code

I tried `report with form` but it does not work for me in `APEX 20.x` due to restrictions setting done to it. So want to achieve using `PL/SQL` code.

Please demonstrate with image and code and how to achieve it

Comment: There is a "sample file upload/download" application. Have you checked that ? In older versions the sample applications were included in the bundle. In newer versions they're on github.

Comment: @KoenLostrie : Lots of restriction added not able to add any

Comment: "not able to add any" what ? Applications ? Create your own workspace on apex.oracle.com, test the functionality, apply to your own environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if it will help you, but here's how I did on my application :

My table :

```
CREATE TABLE inv_tb_document(
    pk_document INT, --primary key
    nom_document VARCHAR(255) CONSTRAINT ct_nn_nom_document NOT NULL, --document name
    blob_document BLOB CONSTRAINT ct_nn_blob_document NOT NULL, --blob column
    mimetype_document VARCHAR(255) CONSTRAINT ct_nn_mimetype_document NOT NULL, --mimetype column
    charset_document VARCHAR(255), --charset column
    commentaire_document VARCHAR(75) CONSTRAINT ct_nn_commentaire_document NOT NULL, -- irrelevant for your case
    date_document TIMESTAMP(8) CONSTRAINT ct_nn_date_doducment NOT NULL, --irrelevant too
    CONSTRAINT ct_pk_document PRIMARY KEY(pk_document)
);
```

Now, here's what I did for my form :
[image: insert form]

Here are the attributes of my File Browser Item :

[image: attributes of file browser]

---

I don't have any custom code to insert the document on my tables, I hope this could help you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

not an exact answer to your specific question, but if you change Storage Type as Table APEX_xx_Temp. you could go like this:

```
(select filename from apex_application_temp_files  where name = :P1_CHOOSE_FILE)
,(select mime_type from apex_application_temp_files  where name = :P1_CHOOSE_FILE)
,(select blob_content from apex_application_temp_files  where name = :P1_CHOOSE_FILE)
```